# How to copy and change a property of many models from a queryset, in batch?

Tags: django, django-orm

I'm aware that you can force copying an instance of a model by settings its `pk` to `None` and saving

```
myModel = MyModel.objects.get(..)
myModel.pk = None
myModel.save() # -> Creates a new copy
```

What if I want to do this on an entire queryset?

```
MyModel.objects.filter(...)
```

Should I iterate over this and do it one-by-one? Or can this be made more efficiently?

---

Use case:

Every time a new user is created, I need to copy a bunch of models and related models that I assign to him by default:

```
def save(self, **kwargs):
    super(User, self).save(**kwargs)
    for c in MyModelCategory.objects.filter(mymodel__is_default=True):
        c.pk = None
        c.user = self.user
        c.save()
        for s in MyModel.objects.filter(category=c):
            s.pk = None
            s.user = self.user
            s.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an easy way to do this without iterating over the entire queryset.

One way to make this function more efficient is to use `transation.atomic()`, like this:

```
def save(self, **kwargs):
    super(User, self).save(**kwargs)
    with transation.atomic():
        for c in MyModelCategory.objects.filter(mymodel__is_default=True):
            c.pk = None
            c.user = self.user
            c.save()
            for s in MyModel.objects.filter(category=c):
                s.pk = None
                s.user = self.user
                s.save()
```